# error building h5py: deprecated numpy

Tags: python, numpy, version, deprecated, h5py

I'm trying to build h5py from terminal using:
      git clone http://github.com/h5py/h5py.git,
and then cd /h5py, then

```
     sudo python setup.py install.
```

It seems to start building but then encounter some sort of error and fails to build. Please have a look at the log below:

```
> In file included from
> /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1803:0,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/defs.c:287: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:12:2:
> warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining
> NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]  #warning "Using
> deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API
> NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"   ^
> /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:24:2:
> error: #error Should never include npy_deprecated_api directly. 
> #error Should never include npy_deprecated_api directly.   ^ In file included from
> /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:127:0,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1803,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/defs.c:287: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/old_defines.h:5:0:
> warning: "NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API" redefined [enabled by default] 
> #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_9_API_VERSION  ^ In file included from
> /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1803:0,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/defs.c:287: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:3:0:
> note: this is the location of the previous definition  #define
> NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION  ^ In file included from
> /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:127:0,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1803,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/defs.c:287: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/old_defines.h:7:2:
> error: #error The header "old_defines.h" is deprecated as of NumPy
> 1.7.  #error The header "old_defines.h" is deprecated as of NumPy 1.7.   ^ In file included from
> /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:26:0,
>                  from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
>                  from /home/user/h5py/h5py/defs.c:287: /home/saliba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629:1:
> warning: ‘_import_array’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function] 
> _import_array(void)  ^ error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

Any idea on how to fix the deprecation? I have numpy version 1.9.2 and tried to downgrade 1.7.1 but havent found a way.

Thanks :D

Comment: Try with a stable version of h5py and numpy 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

I have just installed `h5py`, and yeah numpy is a dependency.

```
numpy==1.11.2
h5py==2.6.0
```

I encountered h5py installation failure, due to missing hdf5 development library - also had the numpy api deprecation warning all over the stdout:

```
/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/venv_anytime_rc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
```

---

Main cause of failure was missing hdf5 development lib, which got resolved once the I installed the package

For CentOS

```
sudo yum -y install hdf5-devel
```

For Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
```

**Note**: above command will install `hdf5` development lib version `1.8.12`